# Replacing an item in a python list by index.. failing?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, indexing

Any idea why when I call:

```
>>> hi = [1, 2]
>>> hi[1]=3
>>> print hi
[1, 3]
```

I can update a list item by its index, but when I call:

```
>>> phrase = "hello"
>>> for item in "123":
>>>     list(phrase)[int(item)] = list(phrase)[int(item)].upper()
>>> print phrase
hello
```

It fails?

Should be `hELLo`

Answer (score 10):

You haven't initialised `phrase` (The `list` you were intending to make) into a variable yet. So pretty much you have created a list in each loop, it being the exact same.

If you were intending to actually change the characters of `phrase`, well that's not possible, as in python, strings are immutable.

Perhaps make `phraselist = list(phrase)`, then edit the list in the for-loop. Also, you can use [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

```
>>> phrase = "hello"
>>> phraselist = list(phrase)
>>> for i in range(1,4):
...     phraselist[i] = phraselist[i].upper()
... 
>>> print ''.join(phraselist)
hELLo
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> phrase = "hello"
>>> list_phrase = list(phrase)
>>> for index in (1, 2, 3):
        list_phrase[index] = phrase[index].upper()
>>> ''.join(list_phrase)
'hELLo'
```

If you prefer one-liner:

```
>>> ''.join(x.upper() if index in (1, 2, 3) else x for
            index, x in enumerate(phrase))
'hELLo'
```

Comment: there is still a useless `list(phrase)`

Answer (score 1):

Another answer, just for fun :)

```
phrase = 'hello'
func = lambda x: x[1].upper() if str(x[0]) in '123' else x[1]
print ''.join(map(func, enumerate(phrase)))
# hELLo
```

---

To make this robust, I created a method: (because I am awesome, and bored)

```
def method(phrase, indexes):
    func = lambda x: x[1].upper() if str(x[0]) in indexes else x[1]
    return ''.join(map(func, enumerate(phrase)))

print method('hello', '123')
# hELLo
```

Comment: Because using list comprehensions are too mainstream

Comment: What exactly is "non-pythonic" ?

Answer (score 0):

consider that strings are immutable in python You can't modify existing string can create new.

`''.join([c if i not in (1, 2, 3) else c.upper() for i, c in enumerate(phrase)])`

Answer (score 0):

`list()` creates a *new* list. Your loop creates and instantly discards two new lists on each iteration. You could write it as:

```
phrase = "hello"
L = list(phrase)
L[1:4] = phrase[1:4].upper()
print("".join(L))
```

Or without a list:

```
print("".join([phrase[:1], phrase[1:4].upper(), phrase[4:]]))
```

Strings are immutable in Python therefore to change it, you need to create a new string.

Or if you are dealing with bytestrings, you could use `bytearray` which is mutable:

```
phrase = bytearray(b"hello")
phrase[1:4] = phrase[1:4].upper()
print(phrase.decode())
```

If indexes are not consecutive; you could use an explicit for-loop:

```
indexes = [1, 2, 4]
for i in indexes:
    L[i] = L[i].upper()
```